# How to identify the hardware of my phone?

Tags: hardware

I have a china phone and it has a quadcore processor. Now how do i figure out what chipset,processor it has and which roms is it compatible with????

Comment: This may help if Google Play is installed on the device  [List of all devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of [system info apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=system-info) available on the markets. Apart from those monitoring resource usage are also some showing you details on the hardware components, such as [Hardware Info](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.hardwareinfo) and [System Info Droid](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sysinfodroid):

[image: Hardware Info] [image: Hardware Info] [image: System Info Droid]
<sup>*Hardware Info* and *System Info Droid* (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

These two should tell you everything you need – except for "which roms is it compatible with". That's always hard to tell if you don't know the exact name (and sometimes even if you do).

Answer (score 0):

"hardware info" is a free app that can show you the capabilities of your phone.like proccessor rom chipset type etc... just install it on your phone and once you start it,it will show you all the hardware details of your phone.

Comment: It would help to include a link to the app you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Download this one - [Droid Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkwired.droidinfo). This is the best one for newbies. You can find more apps similar to this by searching in Play Store. Your search string can be 'Device Hardware'.